# how to remove string before second ":" in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to get last two strings `email@email.com:namesurname` from those strings. I know how to remove the last item after `:` with `:.*`  but how can i do that for first also for those below? Just give me a recommendation if anyone can.

> jobapplication:::2017-05-29:email@email.com:namesurname

also like this one:

> skills:email@email.com:namesurname

I dont have idea to start it and there are around 3200 job applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered recording a quick macro in which you do it once, replace or whatever, then press home home and down arrow to advance to the next line?  Then you could do Run For Rest of File and it'd be done.  (Make a backup first. ;))  I find the quick macro feature of Notepad++ comes in handy for this kind of thing, and easier (for some of us) to remember how to use than arcane regexes.

Answer (score 2):

Use the regular expression `^.+\:(?=\w+\@)` to find unwanted string then replace all matches by empty string.

[image: Screenshot]